# Scrapy - How to access a returned dictionary in parse from another parse function

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to use parse as a central hub to gather dicts from other parse functions since I need to use multiple URL and domains but I can't seem to figure out how to get all the data back into one dictionary. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
def parse(self, response):
    request_1 = scrapy.Request(domain_1_url, callback = parse_2)
    request_2 = scrapy.Request(domain_2_url, callback = parse_3)
    #unpacks the two dicts from the 2 requests and return them as 1 to the pipeline
    yield {**request_1, **request_2} #what I want to do, doesn't work because they are requests, not dicts

def parse_2(self, response):
    yield {'someKey': 'some value'}

def parse_3(self, response):
    yield {'someOtherKey': 'some more values'}
```

Is there someway I can achieve this? Or is there a better way to do it like throwing everything to the pipeline and have that handle combining the data instead?

**EDIT:**

I thought about passing an Item object to the other requests thinking that modifying it in the other requests will also modify the one in the main parse because of Python's "call-by-object" properties:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = CustomItem()
    request_1 = scrapy.Request(domain_1_url, callback = parse_2)
    request_1.meta['item'] = item
    request_2 = scrapy.Request(domain_2_url, callback = parse_3)
    request_2.meta['item'] = item
    print(item) #still empty
    yield item

def parse_2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['someKey'] = 'some value'
    yield item

def parse_3(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['someOtherKey'] = 'some more values'
    yield item
```

Not quite sure why this doesn't work but the item object in parse() is still empty after calling the 2 requests

Comment: You can have a look at [inline-requests](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests/) or do the aggregation as a 2nd step, grouping on some key

Comment: Alternatively, you could use request chaining as described in the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions).

Comment: @TomášLinhart I tried passing a Item object and modifying it in all 3 parses and returning the item object. The problem is that even though I passed the item object to the other parse functions, the item in the main parse was not altered at all

Comment: @EdwardFu You probably got wrong the way it's supposed to work. When you chain requests, you pass the item in requests' `meta` between each subsequent requests (possibly modifying it in the callbacks) and finally yield the item in callback function of your very last request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to [@TomášLinhart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028502/scrapy-how-to-access-a-returned-dictionary-in-parse-from-another-parse-functio/45047607#comment77038852_45028502) for the solution in the comments above

What I ended up doing is chaining the 3 parses instead of using one as a central hub. I really dislike this solution since parse_2 and parse_3 has no relationship with one another and they each crawl on different domains in my situation so if anyone have a more elegant solution please feel free to answer

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = CustomItem()
    request_1 = scrapy.Request(domain_1_url, callback = parse_2)
    request_1.meta['item'] = item
    yield request_1

def parse_2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['someKey'] = 'some value'
    request_2 = scrapy.Request(domain_2_url, callback = parse_3)
    request_2.meta['item'] = item
    yield request_2

def parse_3(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['someOtherKey'] = 'some more values'
    yield item
```

Comment: This is what I meant in the comment above. An alternative (and better designed) solution could probably be implemented using Twisted `Deferred`s, but don't know exactly how and if it woulnd't break any of Scrapy's design principles (e.g. pipelines).

Comment: gotcha I see what you mean now, thanks for the help :)